# best way to save image and text in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

So I have a Canteen Ordering Application project.

I'll be using Android Studio as my IDE, Firebase as Database, and Java as the Programming Language.

We have a feature that lets the Admin of the Application post the Available Food per day, thus we need to store an image and text (description of the food.) to the database and later on display it in the Customers UI with an Add to Cart Button.

I'm kinda lost on where should I store the text and image since I have lots of options like Realtime Database, Cloud Firestore, and Firebase Storage.

Answer (score 0):

You'll typically store the image in Cloud Storage (through the Firebase SDK), and then store a reference to that image (either its path, or a download URL) in the database. To decide what Firebase database to use, have a look at the [database recommender](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/rtdb-vs-firestore) in the documentation.